# Changing data display language on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, internationalization, labeling

I want to make a simple outline map on QGIS with basic city names. I downloaded the map from Nature maps but the city names keep appearing in greek, even though I changed the locale and application language.

What should I do to make the names appear in english?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You would need to change the column used for labeling. The NaturalEarth dataset contains the `NAME` column, with the town name in its original language, as well as several translations. You might be displaying `name_el`. If you want to always show the name in English, select `name_en`.

Let's note that it is purely a la labeling aspect, so it is unrelated to the application language or your locale.

Comment: I wouldn't totaly agree that this is purely a labeling aspect and not related to user locale settings, since locale settings can be uses to automatically determine column used for labeling, cp. answer below.

Comment: @JochenSchwarze Until you write/use custom code tailored to a specific dataset, the two concepts are indeed unrelated. (nice function by the way)

Answer (score 1):

In **QGIS 3** under *Project|Project Properties|Variables* you find a Global called `qgis_locale` wich you can use to automatically determine the column used for labeling. Use the following expression for this:

```
eval('"name_' || @qgis_locale || '"')
```

The `@` references a variable, the string concatenation `"name_' || @qgis_locale || '"` will give you the column (here: `"name_el"`) and  `eval()` does evaluate the column name to its value.

Since in **QGIS 2** there is no such variable, so one might define a custom function to get the first two letters of the user locale (`en`, `de`) and use this for the expression that automatically selects the column to get labels from:

```
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Locale')
def getLocale(feature, parent):
    return QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")[0:2]
```

[image]

The expression then changes to

```
eval('"name_' || getLocale() || '"')
```

[image]

With this the language of the labels in the map should directly depend on the users locale settings.

Comment: For your information, there is a global variable called 'qgis_locale'. So no need for the python function.

Comment: you are right for QGIS 3, but @qgis_locale does not exists in QGIS 2, so in QGIS 2 I think you can't get around the python function. But thanks for this hint, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem importing [Natural Earth Quick Starter Kit](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) using **QGIS version 3**, all my labels were in Russian (Cyrillic). Similarly, [Wikipedia Maps Tile Server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers) displayed country labels in each country's language, i.e. "Thailand" was labeled in Thai characters, "Japan" was labeled with Kanji, etc.

---

## Here's how I fixed it:

1. Open QGIS (version 3), Click **Project** in the upper-left corner of your workspace.
2. Select **Properties**
3. Click **Variables** in the column on the left of the *Project Properties* viewport.
4. Find `project_language` variable.
5. **Replace** the value `name_el` with the new value `name_en`
6. Click Apply
7. Click OK
8. Restart QGIS
9. (Re)Open the file: `Natural_Earth_quick_start_for_QGIS_v3.qgs`
10. Labels in English.

---